# React Native AppleId Authentication: email null with "hide my email" option

Tags: react-native, apple-sign-in, apple-authentication, sign-in-apple

### Environment:

- Emulator: iPhone 14 Pro
- [@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication)

I have following code for AppleId SignIn:

```js
let appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
  requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
  requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME],
})

console.log('Email: ', appleAuthRequestResponse.email) // getting null
```

Here on the last line I am getting **email = null**

[image]

What is wrong with the Apple Authentication?

**Thank you mates in advance!**

Comment: Are you rendering the login page from that specific [npm package](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication)?, i think it could be another NPM package that let you connect with apple authentication api to have running a react app in a local environment for testing purposes